# Laravel 10 + Yajra datatables aggregate based on union of 2 models

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I have one particular error that I cannot understand, even if the SQL query works like a charm using MySQL

The query() function:

```
public function query(Order $model)
{
    $request = $this->request();

    $model  = $model
            ->leftJoin('p_inquiry', 'p_inquiry.id', '=', 'p_orders.inquiry_id')
            ->leftJoin('client_details as partner', 'partner.user_id', '=', 'p_orders.partner_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'partner.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftjoin('currencies', 'currencies.id', '=', 'p_orders.currency_id')
            ->leftJoin('payments', 'payments.p_order_id', '=', 'p_orders.id')
            ->leftJoin('countries', 'p_inquiry.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->leftJoin('p_payment_details', 'p_payment_details.inquiry_id', '=','p_orders.id')
            ->select('partner.company_name as partner_name'
                     , 'p_orders.amount as to_pay', DB::raw('null as to_be_paid'), 'currencies.currency_symbol' 
            );
     
    $model1 = Inquiry::
            join('p_orders', 'p_inquiry.id', '=', 'p_orders.inquiry_id')
            ->leftJoin('client_details as partner', 'partner.user_id', '=', 'p_inquiry.client_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'partner.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftjoin('currencies', 'currencies.id', '=', 'p_inquiry.currency_id')
            ->leftJoin('payments', 'payments.inquiry_id', '=', 'p_inquiry.id')
            ->leftJoin('countries', 'p_inquiry.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->leftJoin('p_payment_details', 'p_payment_details.inquiry_id', '=','p_inquiry.id')
            ->select('partner.company_name as partner_name'
                        , DB::raw('null as to_pay'), 'p_inquiry.amount as to_be_paid', 'currencies.currency_symbol'
            );

    $subQuery = DB::query()->fromSub(function($query) use($model, $model1) {
        $query->select('partner_name', DB::raw('sum(to_be_paid) as to_be_paid'), DB::raw('sum(to_pay) as to_pay'), 'currency_symbol')
            ->from($model->union($model1))
            ->groupBy(['partner_name','currency_symbol'])
            ->orderBy('to_be_paid', 'desc');
    }, 't_sum')
    ->mergeBindings($model->union($model1)->getQuery())
    ->get();

    return datatables()->of($subQuery)->make(true)

}
```

While using that code, the error issued is: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
The SQL query that is generated works perfectly is as follows:

```
select * from (select `partner_name`, sum(to_be_paid) as to_be_paid, sum(to_pay) as to_pay, `currency_symbol` from ((select `partner`.`company_name` as `partner_name`, `p_orders`.`amount` as `to_pay`, null as to_be_paid, `currencies`.`currency_symbol` from `p_orders` left join `p_inquiry` on `p_inquiry`.`id` = `p_orders`.`inquiry_id` left join `client_details` as `partner` on `partner`.`user_id` = `p_orders`.`partner_id` left join `users` on `partner`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `currencies` on `currencies`.`id` = `p_orders`.`currency_id` left join `payments` on `payments`.`p_order_id` = `p_orders`.`id` left join `countries` on `p_inquiry`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` left join `p_payment_details` on `p_payment_details`.`inquiry_id` = `p_orders`.`id` where `p_orders`.`deleted_at` is null) union (select `partner`.`company_name` as `partner_name`, null as to_pay, `p_inquiry`.`amount` as `to_be_paid`, `currencies`.`currency_symbol` from `p_inquiry` inner join `p_orders` on `p_inquiry`.`id` = `p_orders`.`inquiry_id` left join `client_details` as `partner` on `partner`.`user_id` = `p_inquiry`.`client_id` left join `users` on `partner`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `currencies` on `currencies`.`id` = `p_inquiry`.`currency_id` left join `payments` on `payments`.`inquiry_id` = `p_inquiry`.`id` left join `countries` on `p_inquiry`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` left join `p_payment_details` on `p_payment_details`.`inquiry_id` = `p_inquiry`.`id` where `p_inquiry`.`deleted_at` is null and `p_inquiry`.`company_id` = 2)) as `` group by `partner_name`, `currency_symbol` order by `to_be_paid` desc) as `t_sum`;
```

I am not sure where the mistake is, but I have been trying to fix it, and even tried a different method for the aggregation:

```
$result = DB::query()
    ->fromSub($model->union($model1),'t_sum')
    ->select('partner_name', DB::raw('sum(to_be_paid) as to_be_paid'), DB::raw('sum(to_pay) as to_pay'), 'currency_symbol')
    ->groupBy(['partner_name','currency_symbol'])
    ->orderBy(['to_be_paid','desc']);

return $result;
```

This time, the error is:

```
"message": "Yajra\\DataTables\\DataTables::eloquent(): Argument #1 ($builder) must be of type Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thank you